# How does $max work over an array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Take an example collection with these documents:

```
client.test.foo.insert_one({
    'name': 'clientA',
    'locations': [
        {'name': 'a', 'sales': 0, 'leads': 2}, 
        {'name': 'b', 'sales': 5, 'leads': 1}, 
        {'name': 'c', 'sales': 3.3, 'leads': 1}]})
client.test.foo.insert_one({
    'name': 'clientB',
    'locations': [
        {'name': 'a', 'sales': 6, 'leads': 1},
        {'name': 'b', 'sales': 6, 'leads': 3},
        {'name': 'c', 'sales': 1.3, 'leads': 4}]})
```

How does $max determine which item in the location array is maximal?

```
client.test.foo.aggregate([{'$project': {'maxItem': {'$max': '$locations'}}}]))
```

Returns:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5b995d72eabb0f0d86dceda5'),
  'maxItem': {'leads': 1, 'name': 'b', 'sales': 5}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5b995d72eabb0f0d86dceda6'),
  'maxItem': {'leads': 3, 'name': 'b', 'sales': 6}}]
```

It looks like `$max` is picking to sort on `sales` but I am not sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects
which states:

MongoDB’s comparison of BSON objects uses the following order:

1. Recursively compare key-value pairs in the order that they appear
   within the BSON object.
2. Compare the key field names.
3. If the key field names are equal, compare the field values.
4. If the field values are equal, compare the next key/value pair (return to step 1). An object without further pairs is less than an
   object with further pairs.

which means that if `sales` is the first key in the bson object then I have my answer.  I'm using pymongo and python dictionaries aren't ordered, so I switched to bson.son.SON and re-did the example:

```
client.test.foo.delete_many({})
client.test.foo.insert_one({
    'name': 'clientA',
    'locations': [
        bson.son.SON([('name', 'a'), ('sales', 0), ('leads', 2)]), 
        bson.son.SON([('name', 'b'), ('sales', 5), ('leads', 1)]),
        bson.son.SON([('name', 'c'), ('sales', 3.3), ('leads', 1)])]})
client.test.foo.insert_one({
    'name': 'clientB',
    'locations': [
        bson.son.SON([('name', 'a'), ('sales', 6), ('leads', 1)]), 
        bson.son.SON([('name', 'b'), ('sales', 6), ('leads', 3)]),
        bson.son.SON([('name', 'c'), ('sales', 1.3), ('leads', 4)])]})
```

And now its sorting by name:

```
client.test.foo.aggregate([{'$project': {'maxItem': {'$max': '$locations'}}}]))
```

Returns:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5b99619beabb0f0d86dcedaf'),
  'maxItem': {'leads': 1, 'name': 'c', 'sales': 3.3}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5b99619beabb0f0d86dcedb0'),
  'maxItem': {'leads': 4, 'name': 'c', 'sales': 1.3}}]
```